# Clean up Datatable

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have a data.table

`head(LocalCodes, n= 20)
                                                          Local Codes
 1:                                              Crane, Indiana  0189
 2:                                            Rutland, Vermont  0401
 3:                                                          NA  5003
 4:                  Naval Air Station Patuxent River, Maryland  5001
 5:                                      Williamsburg, Virginia  7408
 6:                  District of Columbia, District of Columbia  0132
 7:                                       Newport, Rhode Island  1702
 8:                                                          NA  1805
 9:                                                          NA  5306
10: Washington DC, District of Columbia / Kansas City, Missouri  2210
11:                                       Kansas City, Missouri  0503
12:                                         Arlington, Virginia  0501
13:                                            Phoenix, Arizona  0301
14:                         Washington DC, District of Columbia  0132
15:                                                          NA  5001
16:                                          Collbran, Colorado  0303
17:     Washington DC, District of Columbia / Norfolk, Virginia  1102
18:                                         Minot, North Dakota  1802
19:                         Washington DC, District of Columbia  2005
20:                                         Pine Knot, Kentucky  4749`

I am attempting to use `Good <- LocalCodes[ , list( LocalCodes$Local <- unlist( strsplit( LocalCodes$Local , " / " ) ) , by=LocalCodes$Codes)]`
To split up `Local` on the "/" and Keep the same `Codes` in a new data table.

I keep receiving an error `Error in strsplit(LocalCodes$Local, " / ") : non-character argument`

I did try add `as.character(LocalCodes$Local)` to `Good` to get rid of the error, but then the data.table works incorrectly. It separates the `Local` but then the `Codes` do not line up because `Local` is now a character.

Is there a way to separate `Local` and maintain `Codes` on the correct `Local`

Example:

                                                          `Local Codes
8:                                                           NA  1805
9:                                                           NA  5306
10:                                       Kansas City, Missouri  2210
11:                         Washington DC, District of Columbia  2210 
12:                                       Kansas City, Missouri  0503
13:                                         Arlington, Virginia  0501
14:                                            Phoenix, Arizona  0301
15:                         Washington DC, District of Columbia  0132
16:                                                          NA  5001
17:                                          Collbran, Colorado  0303
18:                                           Norfolk, Virginia  1102
19:                         Washington DC, District of Columbia  1102`

Using: Plyr, Dplyr, Data.Table

EDIT:
 Here's the dput output:

`dput(head(LocalCodes, n= 20))
structure(list(Local = list("Crane, Indiana", "Rutland, Vermont", 
    "NA", "Naval Air Station Patuxent River, Maryland", "Williamsburg, Virginia", 
    "District of Columbia, District of Columbia", "Newport, Rhode Island", 
    "NA", "NA", "Washington DC, District of Columbia / Kansas City, Missouri", 
    "Kansas City, Missouri", "Arlington, Virginia", "Phoenix, Arizona", 
    "Washington DC, District of Columbia", "NA", "Collbran, Colorado", 
    "Washington DC, District of Columbia / Norfolk, Virginia", 
    "Minot, North Dakota", "Washington DC, District of Columbia", 
    "Pine Knot, Kentucky"), Codes = list("0189", "0401", "5003", 
    "5001", "7408", "0132", "1702", "1805", "5306", "2210", "0503", 
    "0501", "0301", "0132", "5001", "0303", "1102", "1802", "2005", 
    "4749")), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L)`

Comment: If you had posted `dput( head(LocalCodes, n= 20) )` instead of the console representation, people would have been able to reconstruct that object much easier. As it stands I would need to run `read.fwf` after counting spacing (which I find painful so I don't do it.)

Comment: I have added the `dput` output.

Comment: My answer didn't succeed with more than one item containing a "/". I got my strategy to work on a variant of your data.table object, but in the process discovered that _your_ structure is unfortunately non-standard. A typical data.table is NOT a list of lists. That sort of structure is notorious for messing up data.frame operations and apparently also messes up data.table ones as well. You should first search SO for methods of fixing malformed data.table objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My original answer didn't succeed with more than one item containing a "/". I got my strategy to work on a variant of your data.table object, but in the process discovered that your structure is unfortunately non-standard. Notice that dput output starts with

> structure(list(Local = list("Crane, Indiana",

A typical data.table is NOT a list of lists. That sort of structure is notorious for messing up data.frame operations and apparently also messes up data.table ones as well. Here's what will fix your data object so it looks like an "ordinary" datatable.

```
LocalCodes[ , names(LocalCodes) := lapply(LocalCodes,unlist)]
#> dput(LocalCodes)
# structure(list(Local = c("Crane, Indiana", ...
```

Now it's not a list of lists. So now try to handle the cases where there are slashes on the interior of strings separately from those where there are not and then rbind them together:

```
 rbind( LocalCodes[grepl("/",Local) ,
            cbind( data.table(Local=unlist( strsplit(Local, split="/")),
                                     Codes=rep(Codes,each=2)))],
        LocalCodes[!grepl("/",Local)] )
                                         Local Codes
 1:       Washington DC, District of Columbia   2210
 2:                      Kansas City, Missouri  2210
 3:       Washington DC, District of Columbia   1102
 4:                          Norfolk, Virginia  1102
 5:                             Crane, Indiana  0189
 6:                           Rutland, Vermont  0401
 7:                                         NA  5003
 8: Naval Air Station Patuxent River, Maryland  5001
 9:                     Williamsburg, Virginia  7408
10: District of Columbia, District of Columbia  0132
11:                      Newport, Rhode Island  1702
snipped-----
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I tried the same method on `Codes`. The end goal is to use the `table` function to count up each occurrence. But after I apply `table` I have multiples of unique items. So I have tried different ways to verify each instance is unique, and they all seem to be unique. Is there a way to collapse multiple instances after removing " / "? I can create a new post if needed.

Comment: There is a duplicated function for data.tables. Just remove the duplicates before tabulation.

Comment: In lies the problem, since all of these are needed to have an accurate count. Just removing the duplicates skews the count. I need a function that collapse the functions in to the overall total.

Comment: I fear the question is morphing in a manner I cannot follow. What you consider an "accurate count" is not well defined, nor is what is meant by "collapse the functions", and both notions seem tangential (or orthogonal?) to the original question, which didn't request counting (or collapsing) of anything. Time for an new question that includes a [MCVE]